Finding the coefficients of two mixed signals, knowing the original signals
I know the signals $a \!\left[ n \right]$ and $b \!\left[ n \right]$. I have also the signal $c \!\left[ n \right]$ that is a mix of these two signals
$$ c \!\left[ n \right] = k a \!\left[ n \right] + l b \!\left[ n \right] \tag{1} $$
What would be possible to find the coefficients $k$ and $l$? Would it be possible to find $k$ and $l$ if they were time dependent?

Can I edit this to be consistent with Hilmar's answer?  That would be changing continuous-time functions to discrete-time?  Maybe change the function names?

Yes I’ve just edited it to change it to discrete-time but feel free to edit it as much as you want to make it clearer.


What would be possible to find the coefficients $k$ and $l$?

Assuming that $a \!\left[ n \right]$ and $b \!\left[ n \right]$ are uncorrelated. That's fairly easy -- you determine the coefficient by defining an error function
$$E[n] = \sum (c[n] -k \cdot a[n])^2 $$
and then minimizing it. If you run the math you get
$$k \approx \frac{\sum c[n]a[n]}{\sum a^2[n]} $$
If $a \!\left[ n \right]$ and $b \!\left[ n \right]$ are correlated or partially correlated, things get a bit more tricky and the solution depends on the correlation.

Would it be possible to find $k$ and $l$ if they were time-dependent?

Not without putting some constraint on the time dependency. If $k$ and $l$ change reasonably slowly, you can simply run the equation above over chunks of the signal where they are mostly constant. If $k \!\left[ n \right]$ has the same bandwidth as $a \!\left[ n \right]$, then $k \!\left[ n \right] \cdot a \!\left[ n \right]$ is a completely new signal and $a \!\left[ n \right]$ is not recoverable.
